# Own user pool for Amazon Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to specify my own (custom) user pool for Amazon Cognito in order to store authenticated users (all user details) in my own database?

Comment: Are you talking about using your own custom identity provider with cognito? You can skip user pool and connect your own provider with identity pool.

Comment: Thanks! Do we have some managed service for IdP in AWS family which simplifies the process of own IdP creation?

Comment: Cognito User Pool is the service which lets you create identity provider on AWS. Which is why it is one of the possible sources in Identity pool. What kind of details are you looking to store? Other than password you can store all details from userpool in your own database.

Comment: I'd like to store all user details in my own database in order to be not fully locked on one technology.

Comment: How to create own IdP on AWS in such a case?

Comment: There is no other specific service on AWS for this. You will need to create your own using EC2/lambda, API gateway, and RDS/DynamoDB.

Comment: Strange.. what is the purpose of keeping user passwords inside Cognito User Pool? Just to lock customers on Cognito or what?

Comment: Because it is a managed service which handles security for you. You don't have to worry about hashing and salting your passwords. You don't have to worry about SRP. There are also certain compliance requirements you have to keep in mind. NOBODY, not even admins should have access to user passwords.

Comment: I apologize, but I think this is just a matter of password location. With a current Cognito setup, admins from AWS side have access to user passwords instead of mine. There are no conceptual differences here. I may provide the same level of security.

Comment: Sure, but AWS has policies built around who can access customer data. These policies make the solution compliant with various security standards.  Amazon Cognito is HIPAA eligible and PCI DSS, SOC, ISO/IEC 27001, ISO/IEC 27017, ISO/IEC 27018, and ISO 9001 compliant. If you don't need all these or if you want to implement a solution on your own which complies to all these standards, you can of course do it. But it is complicated and takes a lot of time. Which is why cognito exists in the first place. To speed up your development.

Comment: But to answer your question, you can use services like ec2/lambda and apigateway and RDS to create a custom authentication process. You will need to make this openID compatible to be able to use it with cognito identity pools.